# certificate authority

Tags: certificates

**hi guys,**
is there a pseudonym in the certificate ? , I read papers that use the certificate authority, and between the components of the certificate, there is a pseudonym.

Comment: Do you mean X.509 certificates as used in TLS, SSH  certificates, or one of the other less common sorts of certificate? They're all different. The universal thing is that they bind a name of some sort (person's name, company name, domain name, email address, pseudonym, etc) to a public key.

Comment: I think this is mainly something that PGP certificates are concerned about. Is this about PGP?

Comment: yes I mean x.509, can i use th PGP certificate for the communication in the ad hoc network????

Comment: If you have a question about a specific paper, it's helpful to include a link to it.

Comment: Maybe "SubjectAlternativeName" could be a "pseudonym"?